# Express JS Save image on server

Tags: node.js, express, image-uploading

I am sending image from my iPhone App to server. Restful API is in express JS. 
I am getting image on server using POST request. I am able to print the binary data but not able to store it properly. When I open the image from specified location,its corrupted. Here is my express js code.

```
app.post('/api/pictures',function(req,res){
console.log(req.headers);
    var body = '';
    filePath = 'C:/Users/Desktop/restful/image.png';
    req.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    body += data;
});

 req.on('end', function (){ 
     fs.appendFile(filePath, body, function() { 
     res.end(); 
     });
   });
  res.send("Success!");
});
```

My req.headers is

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Where as I am getting this response on client side

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 8;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 14 Jan 2015 16:15:01 GMT";
"X-Powered-By" = Express;
 } }
upload completed, response: Optional(Success!)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to upload image using connect-multiparty.

```
app.post('/api/uploadimage', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body, req.files); // check console 

fs.readFile(req.files.urForm-data_name.path, function (err, data) {
       fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
      });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a multipart-parsing middleware such as [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), [`multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), [`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable), or [`connect-busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy).

Comment: can you please give me any sample code or tutorial link?

Comment: I searched for sample code of multiparty here https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty 

But didn't find any REST API related sample code or tutorial. What I found is all related to post images from an html form. But I am sending image from the iPhone app. I am very new to javascript. Can you please help me with this? I am really stuck here.

Comment: I am able to get parameters which I am sending from app. Also getting image size. How to retrieve this image data from part? 
 
app.post('/api/uploadimage', function(req, res, next){

  var form = new multiparty.Form();

form.on('part', function(part) {
    if (part.filename) {
            var filename = part.name;
            var size = part.byteCount;
        console.log("filename = "+filename);

        }
    });
form.parse(req);
});